# Дать определение понятиЮ или понятиЯ

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, как правильно: "дайте определение понятиЮ о природе сорбционных процессов", "дайте определение понятиЯ о природе сорбционных процессов" или "дайте определение понятиЮ(я) природы сорбционных процессов"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Дать определение (чему?) понятиЮ**

Вариант "дать определение понятия" в  Нацкорпусе отсутствует.

Но с Вашим примером есть проблемы.

У слова ПОНЯТИЕ есть два значения
1. Мысль, отражающая существенные свойства и необходимые признаки предмета или явления. *П. времени. П. качества. П. треугольника.*
2. Представление о чём-л.; знание, понимание чего-л. *Получить некоторое п. о предмете.*

"Дать определение" можно только понятию в первом значении. Но "природа сорбционных процессов" вряд ли может являться предметом понятия. Вот "сорбционные процессы" - это предмет понятия. Поэтому правильно:

**Дать определение понятию сорбционных процессов.**

или

**Дать понятие** (как представление, знание) **о природе сорбционных процессов.**

Answer (score 4):

Фразу нужно основательно перестроить.

1. Если говорить *только* об окончании, то возможны оба его варианта, но в разных контекстах. Если речь идёт о новом понятии, не имещем определения, или кого-то просят дать своё определение (отличное от общепринятого), то "определение поняти**ю**", то есть определение "дают понятию". Но у понятия может быть и общепринятое, закрепившееся за ним определение (определение  такого-то поняти**я**), которое напр. преподаватель может предложить "дать" ему (а не понятию) при проверке знаний:

> Дайте (мне) определение поняти**я** "сорбционный процесс".

Опустить здесь уточнение "мне" допустимо лишь в порядке разговорного упрощения.

2. Что касается предложного падежа в исходной фразе: выражение "понятие о..." (в значении "начальные сведения" о чём-то) не сочетается с *определением* понятия как устоявшегося представления в какой-либо области знаний, обозначаемого термином. Давая определение, понятие нужно "назвать по имени", которое для ясности можно привести в кавычках (в именительном падеже) или (если оно достаточно короткое) привести его без кавычек в родительном падеже:

> Дайте определение поняти**ю** "сорбционный процесс".
>
> Дайте определение поняти**ю** сорбционного процесса.
>
> Дайте мне определение поняти**я** "сорбционный процесс" - хочу в нём
>   разобраться.

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, есть понятие "сорбционные процессы", именно во мн. ч.
Сорбционные процессы — это физико-химические процессы поглощения газов и жидкостей или растворенных в жидкости веществ твердыми телами или другими жидкостями

Comment: Интересно, зачем преподавателю при проверке знаний какое-то определение? Он что некомпетентен?